# Setting sa login password as 'sa' resets automatically and windows defender gets activated saying 'Found some malware'

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, passwords, windows-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2008R2 on my server, and the server is running on 'Windows server 2016'
When i Set login password as 'sa' for my user sa, it resets automatically after few minutes and windows defender gets activated saying 'Found some malware, Windows defender is removing it' and my applications running on that server crashes until i reset the sa password again.
If i change login password other than 'sa' for user sa, the sql server runs perfectly with out crashing the applications. In my case i have different applications deployed on that server and i cant bear changing the sql server password other than 'sa'.
un-checking the Enforce password policy check box wont even work.

I need help and proper solution, i can't figure out why 'sa' password would effect windows defender ?

How to avoid this resetting of 'sa' password ?

Comment: Please avoid having a password the same as your login name. This looks like the security system is automatically preventing it.

Comment: It never happened to my local machine, where i use same login name and same password.
Apart from that, i have another server running SQL server with the same login name and password and it would work perfectly fine.
If it would be the security system preventing it then it would have effected the other servers too.
Wait!! It might be the case for 'Windows server 2016' only ?

Answer (score -1):

Please Check Your Sql Server Agent Jobs you can found unused Jobs Disable or delete it because it is a malware and that will fix your problem